# AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'createDataFrame' using Spark 1.6

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

Previous questions asking about this error have answers saying all you need to do is update your version of Spark. I just deleted my earlier version of Spark and installed Spark 1.6.3 built for Hadoop 2.6.0.

I tried this:

```
s_df = sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```

And got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4e8b3fc80a02> in <module>()
      1 #creating a spark dataframe from the pandas dataframe
----> 2 s_df = sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'createDataFrame'
```

Does anyone know why? I tried deleting and reinstalling the same 1.6 version but it didn't work for me.

Here are my environment variables that I was messing with to get my pyspark to work properly:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda installer
export PATH="/Users/pr/anaconda:$PATH"

# path to JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

#Spark
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/pr/spark" #version 1.6
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Did I maybe need to install Hadoop separately? I skipped that step because I didn't need it for the code I was running.

Answer (score 33):

`SparkContext` doesn't have, `SQLContext` has:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
```